# Object-like version of ConstructorParameters util type

Tags: typescript

I want to dynamically generate a type for all parameters of a class constructor in TypeScript. I discovered the [ConstructorParameters utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype) but it gives me an array type. This is how I would like to use it:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(public bar: string, public baz: number) {
    }
}

type ConstructorParamsAsObject<T>  = ???

const params: ConstructorParamsAsObject<typeof Foo> = {bar: "Foobar", baz: 30};
const foo = new Foo(params.bar, params.baz);
```

How would I go about definining this generic `ConstructorParamsAsObject` type?

I already try the following approach, but it didn't result in the desired outcome:

```
type FooConstructorParams = ConstructorParameters<typeof Foo>;
type ConstructorParamsAsObject = {
    [K in keyof FooConstructorParams]: FooConstructorParams[K]
}

const foo: ConstructorParamsAsObject = {
    0: "Foobar",
    1: 30
};
```

Comment: Not possible, function/ctor parameter names and tuple lables are unobservable in the type system. See the linked q/a for more information and workarounds.